# How can I make a variable which is outside a form in php?

Tags: php, html

Hello if an input which is inside a form and other input which is outside form , I can set a varible of that input which is inside form , but how Can I make a varible of that input which is outside ?
just like I have an input which name is name and it is inside form and i have another input which name is type when I click on submit button it is showing an error 
Notice: Undefined index: type in B:\xampp\htdocs\gst3\front\test99.php on line 4

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $type=$_POST['type'];
    echo "ok";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test09</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="type" name="type" >
    <form action=""  method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
<input type="submit" name="submit"  value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please paste code as much as possible to understand problem.

Comment: use JavaScript or JQuery to get all input values and then submit form using JavaScript or JQuery

Comment: Can you add an example of what you want to do? Like a pseudo code or something

Comment: yeah ir is possible with javascript , anyhow i wanted with php , ok thanks

Comment: using PHP it's not possible, only one way you can store outside input value in session

Comment: Why is it not part of the form if you need it to be submitted as part of the form?

Comment: because there are two section and each section have different form  , and this is a select option where two option are section1 and section if I select section 1 then I want to submit form with section name too

Answer (score 0):

You need jQuery to get input values outside the form. 
I think following will work for you:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    postData = {};
    postData['outerData'] = $("input[name='type']").val();
    postData['formData'] = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('url', postData);
});
```